# Android Declare global variable fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, global-variables

I'm trying to declare a global variable but without success. I was following [this tutorial](http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.com/2012/04/declare-global-variable-in-android.html) but this doesn't work if I want to transfer a variable from fragment to MainActivity.

First I added this code to my fragment class:

```
public class WebViewFragment extends Fragment{
private WebView myState;

public WebView getState(){
    return myState;
  }
  public void setState(){
    myState = webView;
  }

}
```

And then I added this to my `MainActivity` but it doesn't work:

```
WebViewFragment appState = ((WebViewFragment)getApplicationContext());
WebView state = appState.getState();
```

I get this `error: Cannot cast from Context to WebViewFragment`

Answer (score 2):

Well, you are trying to cast the app context to a fragment, that can't work.
You will have to look up the correct fragment with something like `getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.my_fragment)` and cast that.

In the tutorial he is using the app object, not a fragment. That's a bad idea and should be avoided if possible, since all variables that are inside the app object will not be garbage collected, filling up RAM.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is:

Put this in you Application class:

```
WebView state;
public WebView getState(){
    return myState;
}
public void setState(WebView webViewState){
    myState = webViewState;
}
```

Then in your fragment just do this to set the state:

```
getActivity().getApplicationContext().setSate(state);
```

And this in the activity to get the state:

```
getApplicationContext().getSate();
```

The above code should be divided so you can check if nothing is null.

Comment: I don't fully understand where to put the code. First part of the code that you said I have to put into Application class, which one do you mean? My MainActivity class or my fragment class?

Comment: none of those, as in the tutorial you have posted you should use a class that is subclass of Application and put that there.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and by reading through some of the comments I was able to provide a solution for one case.  I had a custom adapter class that I was building and I needed to modify a global variable from that adapter class.  My global variable was part of a Fragment that was attached to an Activity.  Here's what I did:

In the Fragment I set the global variable:

`public String myGlobalString = "initial_value";`

In the adapter class that I was building, within the getView(...) function I had:

```
MyFragment myFragment = (MyFragment) ((MyActivity) context).getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_my_fragment);
myFragment.myGlobalString = "new_value";
```

This worked for me.  I was trying to modify a value from an EditText within a ListView and so in my ListView adapater I added an `addTextChangedListener` and put my code within the `onTextChanged` function.